# Move from process builder scheduled actions to Lightning Flows

Tags: lightning, process-builder, visual-workflow

We would like to move some of our PBs with scheduled actions to Lightning Flow. These scheduled actions are executed based on a date custom field, for example X days after DeliveryDate (custom date field). The action is to execute an email alert.

I can not find the way to do exactly the same using Flows, do you know if it is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a [Pause](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=flow_ref_elements_pause.htm) element, and specify the resume time based on the value in the field.

[image]